# Tell SBT to collect all my dependencies together

Tags: scala, sbt

When building a web application SBT is able to collect all my jar dependencies into the WAR file.

Is this possible to have SBT put all the jars I depend on in my non-web application into a directory so I can easily put them onto my class path when running the app?

Comment: I would love to a have a command that created *one* jar with all dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can put something like this in your project definition class:

```
val libraryJarPath = outputPath / "lib"

def collectJarsTask = {
  val jars = mainDependencies.libraries +++ mainDependencies.scalaJars
  FileUtilities.copyFlat(jars.get, libraryJarPath, log)
}

lazy val collectJars = task { collectJarsTask; None } dependsOn(compile)
```

and run the task via `collect-jars` in your SBT console. This will copy the scala-library.jar and the jars used for compilation in a directory called `lib` in the same directory as your `classes` directory.

Comment: Thanks Moritz that got me on the right track. It didn't include all my ivy dependencies though.

Comment: The actual version that worked for me was: def collectJarsTask = {
      val jars = publicClasspath.get.filter(x=> !x.isDirectory)
      FileUtilities.copyFlat(jars, libraryJarPath, log)
    }

Comment: I am new to using Build.scala. Please provide more specifics on where to place the above code. Specifically is it inside the BuildSettings or (somehow I do not know how..) in the Project object?

Answer (score 3):

In my honest opinion don't bother with sbt-assembly. I'm new with scala but I'm quite technology agnostic, I handle a lot of technologies and sbt-assembly it's not clean. Just an opinion.

I would recommend you sbt-pack. Awesome piece of work. It will give you the runnable scripts as well, for both.. WINDOWS AND LINUX.

https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack

Answer (score 2):

You can use sbt-assembly to make a fat jar with all dependencies: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: I believe that sbt-assembly is great to creat fat jar, but not to collect dependencies. OP was asking for a tool to collect dependency jars.