# Standalone deployment of Scalatra servlet

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra, sbt-assembly

I implemented a Scalatra servlet and now want to create an executable jar, just like described in this tutorial: http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/deployment/standalone.html

I use IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin for development and sbt to build and run my servlet (I used sbt-idea to generate the project files).
My problem is that the jetty packages that the JettyLauncher in the tutorial uses cannot be found when I try to compile my project.

UPDATE: Using Matt's answer I was able to compile and run the JettyLauncher. However, I still have problems with sbt-assembly (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). I followed the instruction in the readme, but I get the following error when trying to execute the assembly task:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] No such setting/task
[error] assembly
[error]         ^
```

UPDATE 2: Thanks to Matt I now have a working build.scala and I can generate a executable jar using the assembly task. However, sbt-assembly does not add the content of /src/main/webapp to the jar.
I use this folder to store my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files.
If Scalatra can't match a route, it serves these files, which works when running the servlet using container:start. 
Additionally, I store some files that the server needs in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. These files are also not added to the jar.

My build.scala looks like this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import org.scalatra.sbt._
import org.scalatra.sbt.PluginKeys._
import com.mojolly.scalate.ScalatePlugin._
import ScalateKeys._
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._

object SketchlinkBuild extends Build {
  val Organization = "de.foobar"
  val Name = "Foobar"
  val Version = "0.1"
  val ScalaVersion = "2.10.0"
  val ScalatraVersion = "2.2.0"

  lazy val project = Project (
    "foobar",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ScalatraPlugin.scalatraWithJRebel ++ scalateSettings ++ assemblySettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
            "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
            "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
            "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
            "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.6" % "runtime",
            "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "compile;container",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "compile;container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),
            /* Apache commons libraries */
            "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.7", 
            "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
            /* JSON support */
            "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % "2.2.1",
            "org.json4s"   %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.4",
            /* thumbnail library */
            "net.coobird" % "thumbnailator" % "0.4.3"
     ),
     // ignore about.html in jars (needed for sbt-assembly)
     mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
       case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.discard
       case x => old(x) }
     },
     scalateTemplateConfig in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile){ base =>
        Seq(
          TemplateConfig(
            base / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "templates",
            Seq.empty,  /* default imports should be added here */
            Seq(
              Binding("context", "_root_.org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext", importMembers = true, isImplicit = true)
            ),  /* add extra bindings here */
            Some("templates")
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

There are two options of standalone deployment currently:

1. Single .jar using sbt-assembly which contains runtime and webapp resources. Loading resources from the .jar file is quite slow in my experience.
2. Distribution .zip file using `scalatra-sbt` plugin, contains a start shell script, the runtime resources and the webapp resources in folders.

#### 1. Standalone JAR

For a standalone .jar file using `sbt-assembly` you need to add the plugin first to `project/build.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.0")
```

Then you need to modify the project build, e.g. `project/build.scala`. Import the plugin's settings and keys:

```
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import sbtassembly.Plugin.AssemblyKeys._
```

With that you can create settings for the `sbt-assembly` plugin:

```
// settings for sbt-assembly plugin
val myAssemblySettings = assemblySettings ++ Seq(

  // handle conflicts during assembly task
  mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) {
    (old) => {
      case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.first
      case x => old(x)
    }
  },

  // copy web resources to /webapp folder
  resourceGenerators in Compile <+= (resourceManaged, baseDirectory) map {
    (managedBase, base) =>
      val webappBase = base / "src" / "main" / "webapp"
      for {
        (from, to) <- webappBase ** "*" x rebase(webappBase, managedBase / "main" / "webapp")
      } yield {
        Sync.copy(from, to)
        to
      }
  }
)
```

The first defines a merge strategy, the last one copies the static web resources from `src/main/webapp` to `<resourceManaged>/main/webapp`. They will be included in the final .jar in a sub-folder `/webapp`.

Include the settings in your project:

```
lazy val project = Project("myProj", file(".")).settings(mySettings: _*).settings(myAssemblySettings:_*)
```

Now the launcher needs to be created. Note how the resource base is set:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
import org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener

object JettyMain {

  def run = {
    val server = new Server
    val connector = new SelectChannelConnector
    connector.setPort(8080)
    server.addConnector(connector)

    val context = new WebAppContext
    context.setContextPath("/")

    val resourceBase = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("webapp").toExternalForm
    context.setResourceBase(resourceBase)
    context.setEventListeners(Array(new ScalatraListener))
    server.setHandler(context)

    server.start
    server.join
  }
}
```

#### 2. .zip Distribution using `scalatra-sbt` Plugin

You need to add those imports to your SBT `build.scala`:

```
import org.scalatra.sbt.DistPlugin._
import org.scalatra.sbt.DistPlugin.DistKeys._
```

Then you need to add the plugin's settings to your project. The settings are in `DistPlugin.distSettings`.

You can also customize your distribution and add custom memory settings, exports and command line options. Note that those are all optional:

```
val myDistSettings = DistPlugin.distSettings ++ Seq(
  mainClass in Dist := Some("ScalatraLauncher"),
  memSetting in Dist := "2g",
  permGenSetting in Dist := "256m",
  envExports in Dist := Seq("LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8", "LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8"),
  javaOptions in Dist ++= Seq("-Xss4m", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")
)
```

On the SBT prompt you can then type `dist`. The .zip file will be in the `target` folder.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this solution later and set it as accepted answer if it works.

Comment: I tried this and I got 'Error: Main method not found in class loadtest.jetty.Jetty, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)' Please change your Jetty Launcher example because it doesn't work? I also had a lot of trouble getting SBT assembly to find the main class. I think this is because of the equal sign in run although the Scalatra documentation does this as well for the main function?

Comment: This answer is slightly out of date: SelectChannelConnector is no longer available in Jetty v9. Also for the second option you need to mention that developers must create a ScalatraLauncher and ensure jetty deps are now in the compile scope.

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into trouble doing this.

First, you need to make sure that jetty is available at compile time. These two lines:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" %     "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")),
```

Need to have compile in them:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.8.v20121106" % "compile;container",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "compile;container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
```

Second, from your description it sounds like sbt-assembly is not configured correctly. You need to remove (comment out) these lines:

```
lazy val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  version := "0.1",
  organization := "de.foobar",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
)

lazy val app = Project("app", file("app"),
  settings = buildSettings ++ assemblySettings) settings(
    // your settings here
)
```

You will need to add `++ assemblySettings` to your foobar project immediately after `scalateSettings`. Your plugins.sbt file also needs to contain the following line in it:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.0")
```

For reference, I recommend against using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) because you will most likely run into dependency conflicts that will need to be resolved with a [merge strategy](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy). Instead I suggest you use a task that collects your dependencies into a directory (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564690/tell-sbt-to-collect-all-my-dependencies-together) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351280/collecting-dependencies-under-sbt-0-10-putting-all-dependency-jars-to-target-sc)). And then add them to the java classpath using `java -cp /lib/* ...`.

Third, be wary of the Jetty project in Scalatra's GitHub. I used:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet

import org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext

object Jetty {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(8080)
    val server = new Server(socketAddress)
    val context = new WebAppContext()
    context.setContextPath("/")
    context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp")
    context.addEventListener(new ScalatraListener)
    context.addServlet(classOf[DefaultServlet], "/")
    server.setHandler(context)
    server.start()
    server.join()
  }
}
```

Finally, it might be worth double checking your ScalatraBootstrap is in [the usual place](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/project-structure.html).

Hope that helps. If not I can post my entire build.scala for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After adding the compile option, I was able to compile and run the jetty launcher. But I still have problems with sbt-assembly. I'll update my question.

Comment: No problem. I've edited and added some information on sbt-assembly.

Comment: Thanks again for your updated answer. I had to define a merge strategy to ignore the about.html files in the jars, but thanks to your help I now have a executable jar. However, sbt-assembly does not add the contents of /src/main/webapp to the jar. I'll update my question (once again).

Answer (score 1):

For an up to date answer, please refer to these two files (Credits go to Scalatra in Action book):

https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-in-action/blob/master/chapter09-standalone/src/main/scala/ScalatraLauncher.scala

and

https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-in-action/blob/master/chapter09-standalone/project/Build.scala