# Create an executable jar for SBT scalatra webapp using Jetty

Tags: jetty, sbt, scalatra, sbt-assembly, xsbt-web-plugin

I wrote a small scalatra webapp using SBT. Webapp has default jetty plugin configured. Now i want to create an executable jar from that scalatra webapp which should run by simply executing the jar. I am trying to bundle the jar with assembly plugin and create jar But couldn't make it working.

Can someone suggest me how could i solve this problem.

Comment: Does the link provided by @Robin answer your question? If not could you provide more details like the exact reproduction steps and the errors you're seeing?

Comment: Yes. Link suggested by @RobinGreen answers my question. You will also get more detaials at below links : 
http://www.scalatra.org/guides/deployment/standalone.html

for project structure reference, check here : http://www.scalatra.org/getting-started/project-structure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link suggested by @RobinGreen answers my question. 
URL : [Standalone deployment of Scalatra servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856165/standalone-deployment-of-scalatra-servlet)

You will also get more details at below links : scalatra.org/guides/deployment/standalone.html 
For project structure reference, check here : scalatra.org/getting-started/project-structure.html